# Enumeration with auto-numbering starting at 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a better way to create a long list of enumeration with auto-numbering starting at 0? The closest that I can find is:

```
class Color(Enum):
    red, green, blue=range(3)
```

However, the above approach requires knowing the total items in the enumeration beforehand.

Comment: There's an `AutoNumber` in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#autonumber

Comment: What do you gain by starting at zero when the elements are arbitrary?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `AutoNumber` starts at 1, much like the functional API: `Color = Enum('Color', ['red', 'green', 'blue'])`

Comment: Why do you need it to start at `0`, according to the docs enum members evaluate to `True` so starting at `1` was chosen to avoid confusion with `0` being `False`.

Comment: `AutoNumber` isn't defined by the module; it's just an example that you could easily adapt to Python 2 and starting with 0.

Comment: @AChampion not necessarily

Comment: @jonrsharpe understood.

Comment: I tried to use the enumeration as an index to an array which starts at 0, and I don't like to manually assign a value to each item just in case I have to reinsert a new item to the existing enumeration. I have checked the class AutoNumber(Enum) as answered below, however, it seems that you have to use Color.red.value() instead of Color.red

Answer (score 20):

As @jonrsharpe already showed, an Enum can be created like this:

```
Color = Enum('Color', ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'])
```

This will be indexed (starting) by 1.

The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) states, from Python 3.5:

> use the `start` parameter to specify a different starting value

As the documentation states, you can do exactly that:

```
Color = Enum('Color', ['RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE'], start=0)
```

Answer (score 15):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#autonumber) provides a recipe for autonumbering that can easily be adapted to start from zero:

```
class AutoNumber(Enum):
     def __new__(cls):
        value = len(cls.__members__)  # note no + 1
        obj = object.__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj
```

Then you can create it with arbitrary members:

```
class Color(AutoNumber):
    red = ()
    green = ()
    blue = ()
```

---

Alternatively, note that the [functional API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api) can take an iterable of key-value pairs:

```
from itertools import count

Color = Enum('Color', zip(['red', 'green', 'blue'], count()))
```

[`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) is basically an open-ended equivalent of `range`.

---

However, the docs also provide the reason for members generally starting with `1`:

> The reason for defaulting to `1` as the starting number and not `0` is
>   that `0` is `False` in a boolean sense, but enum members all evaluate to
>   `True`.

Starting from zero may lead to confusing behaviour later on.

Comment: your answer is close to what I am looking for, but the statement Color.red == 0 does not evaluate to True, even  I use IntEnum instead of Enum

Comment: @cash why does that matter?

Answer (score 14):

If you prefer declaring a class in an old fashioned way, in Python `3.6.4` you can try something like this:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class MyEnum(Enum):
    FIELD_1 = 0
    FIELD_2 = auto()
    FIELD_3 = auto()

print(list(MyEnum))
```

should result in:

```
>> [<MyEnum.FIELD_1: 0>, <MyEnum.FIELD_2: 1>, <MyEnum.FIELD_3: 2>]
```

If you don't set `FIELD_1` to `0`, then enum property values shall start from `1`.

Answer (score 10):

The OP clarified that their motivation is to use the enum value as an array index, which implies consecutive numbering starting from zero.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) states:

> The goal of the default [autonumbering] methods is to
> provide the next int in sequence with the last int provided, but **the
> way it does this is an implementation detail and may change**.

Hence it may be wise to define the autonumbering method explicitly, for example:

```
from enum import IntEnum, auto
class PrimaryColours(IntEnum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        """generate consecutive automatic numbers starting from zero"""
        return count

    RED = auto()
    GREEN = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
```

This will ensure that the `enum` values are assigned consequtive values starting from zero:

```
print(PrimaryColours.RED.value,
      PrimaryColours.GREEN.value,
      PrimaryColours.BLUE.value)
```

**`> 0 1 2`**

Note that the `value` property can be omitted if the context doesn't require it, *e.g.*:

```
orange = (255, 102, 0)
print(orange[PrimaryColours.GREEN])
```

**`> 102`**

Comment: Simplest and most suitable solution IMHO. Although the documentation has a strange parameter name for the 1st parameter of the method. I have updated also by using leading underscore `_xxx` for unused parameters.

Comment: `_generate_next_value_()` is in fact a static method. The first parameter is not `self` it is the member identifier name. The method works the same way regardless it is or it is not decorated using `@staticmethod` The difference is only when called on an instance which `auto()` does not do.

Comment: Nice! This is similar to what they do in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values), but there they use variable names `name`, `start`, `count`, and `last_values` for the `_generate_next_value_` method. Out of curiosity, why did you choose to prefix the `start` and `last_values` variables with underscores?

Comment: I didn’t - someone else changed it in an edit

Comment: @MartinCR it would be helpful if you revert the wrong edit by Jean-Francois T. Also I would recommend adding the `@staticmethod` decorator to make it clear that it is a static method.

Comment: @pabouk thanks for the heads up:  I didn't know it was possible to revert an edit like that

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong I tried it with the ```@staticmethod``` decorator but enum.py then fails with "staticmethod object is not callable"

Comment: @MartinCR I must say that I did not test it, sorry... but I would not expect the fail. I will test it later.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong: It doesn't work with `@staticmethod` because there is code in the `__setitem__` for the customized `dict` that underpins `Enum` that uses `setattr` to attach the raw `_generate_next_value_` (not passed through descriptor protocol) to the `dict`'s instance. When attached to the instance rather than the class, it doesn't invoke the descriptor protocol on lookup, so `self._generate_next_value_` gets back the `staticmethod` object itself, not the unbound function that you'd get from looking it up on an instance of a class with a `staticmethod`.

Comment: Note: The problem with `staticmethod` objects not being callable [was fixed in 3.10](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87848) (they now delegate to the function they wrap when called), so it might work for people on 3.10+, but not on 3.9 and below.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That figures: I'm on 3.9.

Comment: @MartinCR: Side-note: I suspect the reason the underscores were added was to follow a convention (don't think it's a Python one, I think I've only seen it commonly used in Rust, where [the compiler supports it specially](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55078271/364696)) that underscore prefixes on arguments indicate arguments that must be accepted for whatever reason but not used. That said, it makes sense in Rust because you can't call a function with explicit keyword arguments, in Python, you can, so the convention doesn't make sense unless parameters are forced to be positional-only.

Comment: Why is `_generate_next_value_` required here?

Answer (score 1):

**Just do;**

```
from enum import IntEnum

color = IntEnum('color', ['red', 'green', 'blue'], start=0)
```

**Or if you want to have a class;**

```
class Color (IntEnum):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        start = kwargs.pop('start', None)
        if start is None:
            kwargs['start'] = 0
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This has RuntimeError: super(): no arguments error. How do you use the class?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question and answer because I was looking for a way to set the starting value of a IntEnum with automatic numbering. I found the answer to my question putting together bits and pieces of the answers here.

I am also adding my answer because I think it may be useful to have a general solution.

```
from enum import IntEnum, auto, unique

class MyEnum(IntEnum):
    
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        # name is the item name
        #
        # start is the automatic numbering starting value and 
        # it is exactly what you want to change. Default = 1
        # Set start to whatever number
        # you want. 0 in the case of the current question.
        
        start=0
        
        #
        # count is the number of items in the enumerator so far
        # 
        # last_values is a list of used values so far.

        return IntEnum._generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values)
                
    A = auto()
    B = auto()
    F = auto()
    C = auto()
    D = auto()
    
for e in MyEnum:
    print(f'{e=}')
```

The idea is very simple, your enumerator subclass of IntEnum is overloading the base class *generate_next_value* method setting a different start value.
Very simple, extremely elegant and works for all possible start values.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, I based on the emums.py

```
from enum import IntEnum

class IntEnumZero(IntEnum):
    # Taken from enums.py
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        for last_value in reversed(last_values):
            try:
                return last_value + 1
            except TypeError:
                pass
        else:
            return 0 #<---CHANGED to 0 instead of <start>


class UsbError(IntEnumZero):
    ZERO = auto() # 0
    ONE = auto() # 1
```