# How to use number in Enum?

Tags: python, enums

I have a column in an SQL database with a type defined like so:

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_enum AS ENUM (
    '0',
    '1',
    '2',
    '3');
```

I want to reflect it in my Python code with an `enum.Enum`. But if I try the obvious corresponding code:

```py
class my_enum(enum.Enum):
    0 = 1
    1 = 2
    2 = 3
    3 = 4
```

I get an error like `SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal` - since `0 = 1` isn't valid Python code on its own. Similarly, even if the class were defined, the natural syntax to create enumeration values should be `my_enum.0`, but that is also invalid Python syntax.

How can I create an `Enum` that uses names that are otherwise invalid?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using an enum with an integer range? Are you aiming to limit values in a column to specific integer values? _(Some context can help us solve this problem for you.)_

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what the supposed solution must achieve. Neither part of `0 = 1` is particularly sensible - enum member are *supposed* to be identifiers to give meaning to constants, so at least one side should not be a number. `0 = ...` would make more sense of the RHS were `auto()` or similar, and `... = 1` would make more sense if the LHS were an identifier. [...]

Comment: [...] Such a seemingly nonsensical construction suggests an `Enum` in the Python sense is not actually appropriate. As you note yourself, even if you could *create*  such an enum it could not be properly used since `my_enum.0` is not sensible either. Rather, something like `dict` (to map `n: n+1`), `set` (to define valid values) or even `Literal[0, 1, 2, 3]` (to define a type for valid values) might correspond better to what you have in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59982294/) indicates that there are alternative syntax to the creation of `Enum`, to support the usage of identifiers that may be valid in contexts outside of Python but are otherwise invalid as a Python identifier, such as identifiers that start with a digit (e.g. `0`).  So for your "invalid" use-case, try the following:

```
# Based directly on the linked answer
my_enum = Enum('my_enum', ['0', '1', '2', '3'])
# However, the definition also accept a `dict` to provide a mapping
# Also took the liberty to prefix the value with 'Choice` to avoid implying
# numeric equivalence of `0 = 1`
my_enum = Enum('my_enum', {
    '0': 'Choice 1',
    '1': 'Choice 2',
    '2': 'Choice 3',
    '3': 'Choice 4',
})
```

To retrieve values from this enum, `my_enum.0` being an invalid syntax is correctly identified, but given that objects in Python generally is backed by a mapping, using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) can retrieve the value stored behind invalid identifier, e.g.:

```
>>> getattr(my_enum, '1')
<my_enum.1: 'Choice 2'>
```

---

Generally speaking, in the modern Python 3 landscape, Enums in RDBMS (e.g. SQL databases) are better integrated with using the [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) for use case that need to restrict a field to a set of valid values.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76277425/) shows how SQLAlchemy 2.0's own Enum type ([`sqlalchemy.types.Enum`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum)) can work with `typing.Literal` under the type-hinting paradigm, even though it has historically worked with the builtin `enum.Enum` type.  In such case, a separate mapping (or mappings when i18n is required) may be provided to map the internal values of the enum stored in the RDBMS to the label displayed to end users.