# How to define Pydantic Enum of integer value converted to string as variable name?

Tags: python, enums, fastapi, pydantic

I have a specification in my FastAPI where I need to create pydantic model with Enum where variables names are 0,1,2,3,4,5 in string format. I have tried the below approaches but it fails.

**Approach 1:**

```
class StartMode(str, Enum):
    '0' = 'Unknown1'
    '1' = 'Unknown2'
    '2' = 'Unknown3'
    '3' = 'Unknown4'
    '4' = 'Unknown5'
    '5' = 'Any of the above'
```

**Approach 2:**

```
class StartMode(str, Enum):
    str(0) = 'Unknown1'
    str(1) = 'Unknown2'
    str(2) = 'Unknown3'
    str(3) = 'Unknown4'
    str(4) = 'Unknown5'
    str(5) = 'Any of the above'
```

I have this specific requirement for API creation and it can't be changed.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73401333/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370808/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804) helpful.

Comment: Turns out this can be done, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77938337/).